# Receive Kerberos ticket for admin account by client from server

Tags: c#, authentication, kerberos

Imagine a scenario like this: You want a WPF application to run some Powershell scripts on users computers on behalf of a service desk operator account.
One way to do it is to send plain text service desk operator credentials over HTTPS with the script you want to run and create NetworkCredentials from them. Not that secure but simple enough.

New requested way after security audit is to try to use Kerberos tickets instead of plain text credentials but I'm confused how that would work because as far as I understand Kerberos it is a multistep operation between client, server and Key Distribution Center so I don't understand how server could create a Kerberos ticket for service desk operator and then send it over HTTPS (perhaps there is some other, more Kerberosy way) to the client and client would somehow use it without any type of key validation and so on.. In what way that would be safer without the key validation?

Perhaps there is some type of Kerberos request that client could make to get credentials of an operator but again I don't see how that would be possible and be safe at the same time.

**Does anyone have any experience with that or can point me to an example?**

Btw. the server is running ASP.NET Core if that helps in any way or opens some possibility, and all environments are fully under Active Directory control

Edit 1: After a comment I have to clarify that the WPF application is started under normal end user credentials with almost no priviliges, it contacts server and downloads as script to run and operator credentials so the script does not fail if the script is doing something that requires higher permissions.

Comment: You can run the application under that user, saves having to impersonate the user. Either way, the server and the client need to trust the KDC, so either in the same domain or have a trust relationship between their domains

Comment: The problem is the application is started by a normaln end user without any admin rights and after the application is started it downloads the script and credentials to run. For technical and process reasons it has to be this way

Comment: That doesn't sound very secure. What is to stop a user manually downloading those higher "service desk operator account" credentials and using them maliciously? Instead you should either give a user the rights they need in the first place, or setup a system where they can for example kick off a job that can run at higher privileges. Giving a user access to high level credentials is the essence of insecurity

Comment: First, they cannot download it just by themself, the script must be waiting for them on server, second even if they could download the credentials, they are always paired with the script and thirdly, you at the same paragraph tell me to give them higher user rights, we are talking about hundreds of thousands employees, and tell me it's insecure to give them those operator credentials for a short period of time that they cannot use for anythin else than just running the script

Comment: Then probably the best thing to do is to give them rights to kick off that job, which would be executed with higher rights. Perhaps the machine account can be given those rights, and then the task can be executed under the `NETWORK SERVICE` account. Or perhaps you just need a Group Policy logon script or something like that. Your use case is fully clear: what do these scripts actually do?

Answer (score 0):

Your question kinda seems like you have already made up your mind on how to do this.  If you are interested in a different way here's my answer:

Kerberos has multiple ways to [delegate permissions](https://www.tarlogic.com/blog/kerberos-iii-how-does-delegation-work/), and restrict permissions by resource.  'Shipping' credentials is just high risk and shouldn't be done and won't pass any security audit. You likely need to reframe/change the solution from your existing process.

Your server would have the power to complete the work.  (It would need a principle with the appropriate permission, Use a keytab (not passwords), with delegate permissions only for operators.)  You could use something like [spnego](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00005q4P8hCAE/what-is-the-difference-between-kerberos-and-spnego-and-how-are-these-services-used-in-websphere-application-server?language=en_US) to use kerberos over HTTPS. (If that's a requirement, it's a little unclear from your explanation if that is required or just something you used to do.)

But yeah, you could have a server, have operators access the server over https and use kerberos.  It would be infinitely more secure than downloading a password every time.  Actually most modern browsers support kerberos of SNEGO natively.(Meaning your browser would use your windows user and provide that to the server)

Just so you know.  Kerberos doesn't actually ever ship your password when you login.  (Because shipping credentials is a risk.)

Comment: It's not me who has made up the mind on it. It's the almighty security guys that do not program, just say to other programmers their code is not safe. :-)

Comment: But to clear this up. There is no browser involved in any part of the process, it's all done in C# code in a WPF application with HttpClient and ASP.NET Core app on the other side. There is Pass-the-Ticket Attack that is similar to what they requested but I'm not sure how to do it legaly. Basically they want to send kerberos ticket of an operator account down to users computer, run some tasks with it and then it expires. I think much easier solution would be to randomly changed password of that operator account with each new request but their network  so wide it's hard to see the right path

Comment: I am with your security team, Kerberos is the right tool.  Shipping passwords is the wrong tool.  Look into delegate permissions link in this post and it shows a path forward for you.  If you have a more specific question let me know and I'll try and help.